# How do I make the player face different directions?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So, I've watched a couple of Minecraft videos and I've noticed that players were abruptly changing viewing direction.

For example, if a player is facing towards positive z axis, then using a command he changes viewing direction to negative z axis.

What I'm asking is, is there a command in Minecraft 1.8 that allows you to instantly change direction?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  Can you provide examples?

Comment: So, basically, like in one of the episodes of if other video games were in Minecraft or something on YouTube, the characters in one of the games changed direction, like the whole body was facing down and such, and when you turned back, the body was practically sideways.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to turn yourself around, you can use

> /tp @p ~ ~ ~ ~180 ~

I'm not sure what you're asking, so I can't say for sure whether this answers the question

Answer (score 0):

To abruptly change the viewing angle of the player by a command you can use

/tp playername ~ ~ ~ Yrotation Xrotation

the Yrotation and Xrotation are the angle with respect to Y X axes.

~ ~ ~ indicates that the player will remain at same position.